# Cannot connect to Cassandra in Docker with SSL enabled, getting "Database handshake error: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch"

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose, cassandra, datastax-csharp-driver

Help! I am Running Cassandra in Docker.

I have the hostname set up as "mycassandra".

I have issued a certificate to CN="mycassandra", added a SAN DNS="mycassandra" and even added SAN IP "172.19.0.7" as precautionary measure then created the keystore.

I have set the cluster name to "mycassandra" in cassandra config.

The C# code looks like this (simplified):

```
await Cluster.Builder()
.AddContactPoints("mycassandra")
.WithSSL(new SSLOptions().SetRemoteCertValidationCallback(
                    (sender, certificate, chain, errors) =>
                    {
                        var hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(_serviceConfig.DatabaseHostname);
                        log.LogDebug("Dns.GetHostEntry: " + hostEntry.HostName + " (Cert Subject:" + certificate.Subject + ")");

                        if (errors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
                            return true;

                        throw new Exception($"Hand no shakey error: {errors}");
                    }

                ))
.Build().ConnectAsync("mykeyspace");
```

The one error that appears is :

```
Dns.GetHostEntry: mycassandra (Cert Subject:CN=mycassandra)

Could not establish connection with cassandra. Message: All hosts tried for query failed (tried 172.19.0.7:9042: Exception 'Database handshake error: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch')
---> Cassandra.NoHostAvailableException: All hosts tried for query failed (tried 172.19.0.7:9042: Exception 'Database handshake error: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch')
at Cassandra.Connections.Control.ControlConnection.Connect(Boolean isInitializing)
at Cassandra.Connections.Control.ControlConnection.InitAsync()
at Cassandra.Tasks.TaskHelper.WaitToCompleteAsync(Task task, Int32 timeout)
at Cassandra.Cluster.Init()
at Cassandra.Cluster.ConnectAsync(String keyspace)
```

If I skip on `RemoteCertificateNameMismatch`, everything works fine.

Update:

I inspected the "sender" object param for `SetRemoteCertValidationCallback()`.  It is of SSLStream type, the `sender.targethostname` shows "mycassandra.mydockernetwork" as the value hence not being able to validate against the cert issue.

My docker-compose yaml file:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  mycassandra:
    container_name: mycassandra
    image: cassandra:4.0
    networks:
        mydockernetwork:

networks:
    mydockernetwork:
        name: my_docker_network
        driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cassandra C# driver (which I'll refer to as "the driver") uses .Net's SSL API to connect to encrypted Cassandra nodes. The driver performs a reverse DNS lookup on the IP address to get the node's hostname. This is problematic for Cassandra running in Docker because of its internal networking.

The .Net SSL API returned `RemoteCertificateNameMismatch` because the the `HostName` in the certificate did not match the container's hostname returned by the reverse DNS lookup.

Assuming this is for a development environment, you can either (a) temporarily disable encryption on the Cassandra node, or (b) implement a custom certificate validation in your code (c) using `SSLOptions.SetHostNameResolver()` or (d) your own `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback`.

For details, see [the C# driver TLS/SSL page](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/latest/features/tls/). Cheers!